# How I Can Get Data From Sqlite Database In Electron-js Then Show It Using Document.getElementBy('id').innerHTML

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, sqlite, electron

How I Can Get Data From Sqlite Database In Electrone js Then Show It Using Document.getElementBy('id').innerHTML

The Handle Js File:

```
 function show_tables(){
      var show_tables_query = "SELECT * FROM tables"
      db.get(show_tables_query,function (error,row) {
        if(error){
            console.log("error")
        }
        else{  
            data = []
            data.push(row)
            for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                 alert('<h1>'+data[i]['table_caption']+'</h1>');
            }
        }
    })}
```

The Index.html File

```
<script src="handle.js"><script>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple problems, I guess that is the reason nobody want to reply:

1. I think you use the [sqlite3 module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sqlite3), then you want to use `db.all` instead of `db.get`.
2. Where is data defined? I think you don't need that.
3. then you have a `for` loop over an array of length 1. You want use `.all`, name it `rows` not `row` and loop over the `rows`.
4. instead of alert, You want to have a look at jQuery or use something like this inside the loop:

```js
  var newElement = document.createElement('div');
  newElement.innerHTML = '<h1>' + rows[i].table_caption + '</h1>';
  document.body.appendChild(newElement);
```